# Jquery javascript Collapse using $this

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got four divs that toggle by their title (as you can see below I showed one set).  Each title link class matches the class before the text field class.  Instead of writing the javascipt four seperate times I was hoping to write something dryer using $this to target the current class, and then the current class the class text.

The **important_info_header** class will be a dynamic class for each div.

Not that great with this kind of writing so any help is welcome

**Failed ATTEMPT**

```
 $(this).click(function() {
    $(this+'.text').slideToggle('slow', function() {
     //ani complete.

    });
  });
```

**Working Markup**

**HTML START**

```
    <h4><a href="javascript:void(0)"  class="important_info_header"><%= t("catalog_items.show_lot.important_info_header")%></a></h4>
          <div class="important_info_header text">
              <p><%= t("catalog_items.show_lot.important_info") %></p>
          </div><!-- /text -->


 <h4><a href="javascript:void(0)"  class="important_info_header"><%= t("catalog_items.show_lot.important_info_header")%></a></h4>
          <div class="important_info_header text">
              <p><%= t("catalog_items.show_lot.important_info") %></p>
          </div><!-- /text -->



 <h4><a href="javascript:void(0)"  class="rules"><%= t("catalog_items.show_lot.important_info_header")%></a></h4>
          <div class="rules text">
              <p><%= t("catalog_items.show_lot.important_info") %></p>
          </div><!-- /text -->


 <h4><a href="javascript:void(0)"  class="shipping"><%= t("catalog_items.show_lot.important_info_header")%></a></h4>
          <div class="shipping text">
              <p><%= t("catalog_items.show_lot.important_info") %></p>
          </div><!-- /text -->
```

**HTML END**

```
    $('.important_info_header').click(function() {
    $('.important_info_header.text').slideToggle('slow', function() {
     //ani complete.

    });
  });
```

Comment: my bad, wasn't paying attention, meant (this)

Comment: And what is `this+'.text'` then? So you're adding a string to an object?

Comment: I was trying to.  I'm a ruby developer so I'm a little out of comfort zone. .important_info_header will be a different class for each set of divs that will collapse. The consistent part is each div has a .text. That's why I was trying to use the this (to represent the dynamic class) and the .text after it.  Does that make more sense?

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the class in the selector,

```
  $(($this).attr('class')+'.text').slideToggle('slow', function() {
     //ani complete.

    });
```

Comment: I wonder how you got all those experience points with answers like that...did you actually read the question?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example>>> [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/videsignz/88bW4/)

Add a class to the effect of..  'collapsable' to the four main links

```
<a href='' class="important_info_header collapsable"> //link 1
<a href='' class="rules collapsable"> //link 2
<a href='' class="shipping collapsable"> //link 3
 ....and so on
```

The div directly following has to be the one you want to toggle.

Then your universal click function would be like this (notice the e.preventDefault() , use this instead of javascript:void() in your link..

```
$('.collapsable').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).next().slideToggle( function() { //ani complete.
    });
});
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer.  The click class will be dynamic, that's why I was trying to make it the consistent dynamic variable between each div using (this).  That make more sense? Sorry If i'm articulating  poorly!!!

Comment: How about this...post your four divs so I can get a better handle on it.

Comment: Thanks for your attention!  The .important_header_info is simply the first div. That's the class that will change with each set. I totally wasn't clear. I posted the markup above to hopefully make this clearer.

Comment: May want to add some sort of `href` attribute to your anchors - I've had browsers fail to recognize the link as a link before because of that.

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
$("h4 a").click(function() {
   $("div." + $(this).attr("class") ).slideToggle('slow', function() {
      // function..
   });
});
```

If you can restructure your HTML, I've found this also works quite well

HTML

```
<a href="#sec1" class="expandable">Go to Sec1</a>
<a href="#sec2" class="expandable">Go to Sec2</a>
<a href="#sec3" class="expandable">Go to Sec3</a>

<div id="sec1">Sec 1 content</div>
<div id="sec2">Sec 2 content</div>
<div id="sec3">Sec 3 content</div>
```

jQuery

```
$(".expandable").click(function(){
    $( $(this).attr("href") ).slideToggle("slow");
    // add callback/etc as needed
});
```

It works well because the `href` includes the `#` that the CSS id selector needs. This way, if your user doesn't have JS enabled, link#sec1 will still scroll the page to that id tag on the page.

Comment: Not a bad take on it...choices choices choices ;)